# How to pass values for Ruby method with *args and &block?

Tags: ruby

The method `aasm` is defined as:

```
def aasm(*args, &block)
  if args[0].is_a?(Symbol) || args[0].is_a?(String)
    # using custom name
    state_machine_name = args[0].to_sym
    options = args[1] || {}
  else
    # using the default state_machine_name
    state_machine_name = :default
    options = args[0] || {}
  end
  .......
  #do something else
end
```

Now we need to put the whole `aasm....` in a string and do `eval` on it:

```
  eval("aasm(:test) :column => 'col_name' {#{def_string}}")

  def_string = "state :fresh, :initial => true
                state :move
                event :submit do
                  transitions :from => :fresh, :to => :move
                end"
```

But there is syntax error of `unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input`. We tried to put `(:test) :column => 'col_name'` in `{}` and `[]` and the error is not disappearing. What's the right way to pass all values to `aasm` in one line?

Comment: Is `:column => 'col_name'` suppose to be one of `args` to `aasm`? I would expect that syntax error since after the method call `aasm(:test)` it should be a code block whereas `:column => 'col_name'` is a hash

Comment: I believe so. Another arg is :test. The block is in `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to write it like this instead:

```
eval("aasm(:test, :column => 'col_name') {#{def_string}}")
```